# SQL Server - Select pairs of values from one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is there a way to select pairs of values sequentially from one column in SQL?

i.e. If i have a table with one column of numbers

```
SomeID
------
1
2
3
5
7
11
```

I need to return a set of two columns like so:

```
FirstID    SecondID
-------------------
1          2
2          3
3          5
5          7
7          11
```

Can this be done?

Edit:

I should've mentioned, the order of the first result set matters, and may not be sequential.

i.e. could be

```
SomeID    
5
3
9
8
...

FirstID    SecondID
5          3
3          9
9          8
...        ...
```

Comment: Any ID/sequential column we can use to get "next row"?

Comment: @jarlh currently, no...though I'm starting to realize this is probably an XY problem as my single-column result set is coming from another query and maybe I can work this into there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    t1.SomeID as FirstID,
    t2.SomeID as SecondID
FROM
(
    SELECT SomeID, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY SomeID) as Inc
    FROM TABLE
) t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT SomeID, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY SomeID)-1 as Inc
    FROM TABLE
) t2 ON t2.Inc = t1.Inc
```

works on sql server >= 2005

Comment: I worked ROW_NUMBER into my original (single-column) result set, and this is essentially what I went with

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the windowed function, `LEAD` (or `LAG`)

```
;WITH My_CTE AS
(
SELECT
    some_id as first_id,
    LEAD(some_id, 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY some_id) AS second_id
FROM
    My_Table
)
SELECT
    first_id,
    second_id
FROM
    My_CTE
WHERE
    second_id IS NOT NULL   -- to not get 11, NULL at the end
ORDER BY
    first_id
```

If you don't care about getting that last row then you can just use the CTE query by itself without even using a CTE.

Comment: unfortunately I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and LEAD seems to have been introduced in 2012

Answer (score 1):

Easy way, use a correlated sub-query to return the following value:

```
select t1.id as FirstID, (select min(t2.id) from tablename t2
                          where t2.id > t1.id) as SecondID
from tablename
where t1.id < (select max(id) from tablename)
```

Comment: You won by 3 seconds :)

Comment: @Arvo, maybe I started 4 seconds before you?

Comment: @jarlh I should've mentioned, the order of the first query matters, and may not be sequential

Comment: @McFixit, perhaps you can edit your question (adjust table data and result)?

Answer (score 1):

Simple to left join with the table itself like -

```
Select a.somecol,b.somecol
From TableA as a
Left join TableA as b
On b.someid = a.someid + 1
Where b.someid is not null
```

Comment: Not always +1. (Why left join and also b.someid is not null?)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
declare @t table( SomeID int) insert into @t (SomeID) values
(5),(3),(9),(8)


;with t as(Select someid,row_number() over (order by (select 1)) as  rn 
from @t)        
        Select a.someid,b.someid
        From t as a
        Left join t as b
        On b.rn = a.rn + 1
        Where b.someid is not null
```

Comment: Why `left join` combined with `where b.someid is not null`? Can't you simply do an inner join instead?